# Horizontally compare two dataframes and inset blank rows for differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

Horizontally compare two dataframes and inset blank rows for differences.
I need to see blank rows on the second dataframe where there are no id values

```
df1 =

user    id  Amount
John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000
Tom     2   3000
Claire  3   4000
Mary    4   5000
 
df2 = 

user    id  Amount
John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000
Claire  3   4000
Mary    4   5000
```

To Horizontally compare I am using

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], 
                    axis=1,


Result=

user    id  Amount      user    id  Amount
John    1   1000        John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000        Tom     2   2000
Tom     2   3000        Claire  3   4000
Claire  3   4000        Mary    4   5000
Mary    4   5000
```

What I expect to happen:

```
user    id  Amount      user    id  Amount
John    1   1000        John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000        Tom     2   2000
Tom     2   3000                
Claire  3   4000        Claire  3   4000
Mary    4   5000        Mary    4   5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

First I created a data frame to find the duplicated IDs

```
duplicate = df1[df1['id'].duplicated()]
```

Then I looked up this new dataframe to determine what IDs I needed to insert an empty line after

```
df2= df2.assign(result=df2['id'].isin(duplicate['id']).astype(int))
```

I created a result column to identify the rows where I needed to insert the empty line

```
a = (df2['result'] == 1)
df3 = df2.copy() #make a copy because we want to be safe here
for i in df2.loc[a].index:
    empty_row = pd.DataFrame([], index=[i]) #creating the empty data
    j = i + 1 #just to get things easier to read
    df3 = pd.concat([df3.ix[:i], empty_row, df3.ix[j:]], sort=False) #slicing the df

df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True,) #reset the index
```

Once the empty rows are inserted on df3 then I used pd.concat to display both dfs side by side

```
df_all =pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `merge()` to do a join (use values in columns).  Additionally you need to `rename()` the columns in RHS and use same names in `right_on=` param

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""user    id  Amount
John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000
Tom     2   3000
Claire  3   4000
Mary    4   5000"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""user    id  Amount
John    1   1000
Tom     2   2000
Claire  3   4000
Mary    4   5000"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df2.rename(columns={c:f"{c}_right" for c in df2.columns})
dfm = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={c:f"{c}_right" for c in df2.columns}), 
          left_on=[c for c in df1.columns], 
          right_on=[f"{c}_right" for c in df2.columns],
          how="left")

print(dfm.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
   user  id  Amount user_right  id_right  Amount_right
   John   1    1000       John       1.0        1000.0
    Tom   2    2000        Tom       2.0        2000.0
    Tom   2    3000        NaN       NaN           NaN
 Claire   3    4000     Claire       3.0        4000.0
   Mary   4    5000       Mary       4.0        5000.0
```

Comment: That returns the df1 on the left and df2 columns on the right but df2 data is empty

Comment: yes,  as per what you stated right? side by side comparison.  It's generally not a good idea to have column names duplicated in pandas

Comment: having the underscore in df2 is not an issue for me. The issue is that there is no data being displayed for df2, only the column headers

Comment: that's when you are running with your actual data rather than this sample data?  That would imply that no join is matching....  if you put your data somewhere I can access it happy to take a look

Comment: got it to work eventually (answer added). Thanks for your help Rob!